# Showing compile error in IntelliJ-idea in editor

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Showing compile error in IntelliJ-idea editor.

```
mvn clean install
```

When run it will build successfully and run code normally. But in editor its unable to resolve those import. Some of the import is showing correctly some of the import it's showing error like Blow 
[image]

and actually, the dependency is present in maven dependency list

[image]

In the editor, it showing full of error

I modified build settings, deleted repo, updated maven to the latest version, updated the IntelliJ and tried other suggestion in StackOverflow, still no solution for this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this issue is related to the way we open this project in IntelliJ Idea as `mvn clean install` is working fine for you.

While opening the project in IntelliJ, you should open **maven** project like this:

- New -> Project from Existing Sources -> Select Project -> Import from
  External Model (Select `maven` here)
  [image]
- After this, if you are asked to override .iml (idea files), you can override them.
  [image]

This should hopefully solve your problem.

Answer (score 12):

Try:

- `file` > `invalidate caches / restart`
- maven tool window -> re-import / refresh:
  [image: maven tool window]
- check maven settings of IntelliJ: does it point to the same settings.xml and repository as the maven from the command line? IntelliJ is shipped with it's internal maven and might use different settings / repo than your plain maven from the command line.

Comment: no ..still facing the same issue. maven settings.xml is pointing to correct maven settings.xml

Comment: As a last resort, can you try to create your project anew? (e.g. by coping your project folder without the *iml files / .idea folder) and see if you get the same errors. If you don't it's your (intelliJ) project's config. If you still have the issue, it's perhaps an IntelliJ issue itself. Try to see if there is an update or try the EAP. and/or disable all plugins.

Comment: yeah .. i will try this

Comment: For the worst of issues, sometimes this `Invalidate Caches...` method does NOT work.
I usually start with the `Invalidate Caches...`. method described in this answer.
If that doesn't work, then I follow up with deleting the `.idea` folder, as described in the following answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70408136/1910527

Comment: That works yeah, but please be careful. This should only be used really as a very last resort when you've tried all else and nothing worked. In 10+ years of day-to-day work with IntelliJ, I have only done this myself only once or twice.

You are likely to loose all your project configuration and run configs etc. so be prepared to setup the whole project from scratch again! Ideally, create a back-up of the .idea folder just in case.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue by deleting the local maven repository and restoring the default setting of **Intellij**

1. Go to File --> Manage IDE Settings --> Restore Default Settings
2. Go to File --> Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Build Tools --> Maven --> Get the **Local repository** path and delete it.
3. Open Intellij --> open project --> Go to Terminal --> mvn clean install --> error will disappear after build success

Comment: This worked for me after doing all other steps(in vain)

Answer (score 2):

You can invalidate the cache

```
file -> invalidate caches and restart
```

selecting first two options shown in invalidate cache has worked for, also you might get compile time error in already opened file so, try closing/opening these already opened files which are showing errors.

1. **Clear file system cache and Local History**: remove the virtual file system cache together with the information stored in Local
   History.

   ```
   This action might be helpful for troubleshooting purposes when the usual cache invalidation is not enough to solve the problem.
   ```

   2. **Ask before downloading new shared indexes**: show a notification prompting you to download new shared indexes as they
      become available.

   ```
   Enabling this option also updates your settings for shared project indexes in Settings/ Preferences | Tools | Shared Indexes.
   ```

   3. **Clear downloaded shared indexes**: remove the downloaded shared index files.

Answer (score 2):

If all the above solutions do not really help, make sure you have the necessary plugins installed (such as Lombok). After an Intellij upgrade, I needed to install lombok plugin again. Intellij usually suggests installing it in the pup-up window at the bottom.

Comment: Brilliant!  THIS solved this issue for me.  All I had to do was install the LOMBOK plugin, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, I also had to bump up the heap size for compiler to get past this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try deleteing the .idea folder under your project, close the project completely and re import fresh and it worked for me.

Comment: Downvoted, because this solution can do more harm than good. Please warn people about the consequences when deleting their .idea folder! As they may loose run configurations and environment variable setup that may be hard to restore as it was. So "import fresh" is rather relative and can have major impact depending on people's context. 

Please update your answer accordingly.